# WordPress site - applying CSS when certain criteria are met

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

This is the div on the site for a particular booking - in this example the number 7568 is the tour ID.

```
<div class="tourmaster-template-wrapper" id="tourmaster-payment-template-wrapper" data-ajax-url="https://www.domainname.co.uk/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" data-booking-detail="{&quot;tour-id&quot;:&quot;7568&quot;} >
```

For particular tour ID's I would like to hide another div on the page so is there a way to apply CSS to another div on the page if the data-booking-detail includes certain numbers?

So if data-booking-detail includes 7568 then hide div that offers book now and pay later.

Comment: For css-only solution, it would depend on where the test div and the div to hide are located within the HTML.  eg if they're next to each other or the div-to-hide is a child of the test-div, it's straight forward.  If they can be anywhere in the document, then you'll need some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First, select the specific element. In your case, that element has the ID `tourmaster-payment-template-wrapper` and you are looking for the attribute `data-booking-detail` that contains the value `7568`.

This is an example of how you could hide the second element:

```css
#tourmaster-payment-template-wrapper[data-booking-detail*="7568"] + .hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tourmaster-template-wrapper" id="tourmaster-payment-template-wrapper" data-ajax-url="https://www.domainname.co.uk/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" data-booking-detail="{&quot;tour-id&quot;:&quot;7568&quot;}"></div>

<div class="hide-me">I should be hidden</div>
```